# SwiftUI Present an Alert. Result of 'Alert' Initializer is unused

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to add an alert to my app once a timer finishes I just want a popup to say timer done basically. Whenever I try anything I get this error Result of 'Alert' Initializer is unused.

Any help is appreciated.

```
.onReceive(timerMin, perform: { _ in
            guard isActive else { return }
            if timeRemainingMin > 0 {
                timeRemainingMin -= 1
            } else {
                isActive = false
                timeRemainingMin = defaultTimeRemainingMin
                                    
                Alert(title: Text("This is a test"), message: Text("This is a test message!"))

            }
            
        })
```

Comment: you need to show us more code, mate. There is nothing wrong with the Alert you have. How do you call this, where is it in your view etc...

Comment: I have aded more code. I am trying to call in an .onRecieve

Comment: You can’t just put a View (the Alert) after some code and expect it to appear when code execution reaches that line. That’s not how Swiftui works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"onReceive" is not the right place to show an alert. Show it using ".alert(...)",
such as in this test code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showAlert = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("show alert") {
            showAlert.toggle()
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("This is a test"), message: Text("This is a test message!"))
        }
    }
}
```

So with your timer in "onReceive", just use "showAlert " as in the test button. Something like:

```
.onReceive(timerMin) { _ in
    guard isActive else { return }
    if timeRemainingMin > 0 {
        timeRemainingMin -= 1
    } else {
        isActive = false
        timeRemainingMin = defaultTimeRemainingMin
        showAlert = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification! It is much appreciated. This worked wonders.